# Redefine 'includegraphics' to add space

Tags: macros

I am trying to redefine the command `includegraphics` to add vertical space below and after my image (I am not using the figure environment since I need to place my images quite carefully.)

I was trying something like below but that doesnt work. Any suggestions?

```
  \renewcommand{\includegraphics}{\vspace*{3pt}\includegraphics\vspace*{3pt}}
```

Comment: It's not difficult to redefine the macro. However, what's the motivation to redefine such a widely used macro? Maybe you can provide a small full example to explain why you need this.

Comment: What is wrong with tweaking `\floatsep`, `\textfloatsep`, and `\intextsep`? As pointed out above, I fail to get the motivation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the trim option to enlarge the image vertically. You can use `\setkeys` to do it globally:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-A}%without space

\lipsum[1]

\newpage 

\lipsum[1]

\includegraphics[trim=0pt -1cm 0pt -1cm,scale=0.5]{example-image-A}%with more space

\lipsum[1]

\newpage

\setkeys{Gin}{trim=0pt -1cm 0pt -1cm}

\lipsum[1]

\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-A}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: how many people actually knwo the keyspace for say `trim`?

Comment: @daleif: Sorry I don't understand the question. Do you mean the order of the values?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the actual `\setkeys` in the example. Was just referring to the fact that in order to use `\setkeys` one need to know the proper value for the first argument, something users usually do not.

Answer (score 3):

This uses the `\addvbuffer` service routine from the `verbatimbox` package to condition the `\includegraphics` with, in this MWE, an extra 12pt above and 8pt below the second image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
without using the figure environment

{\centering
\includegraphics[width=2in]{test-image}
\par}

this is the default spacing.  But with \verb|\addvbuffer|,

{\centering
\addvbuffer[12pt 8pt]{\includegraphics[width=2in]{test-image}}
\par}

the gap above and below the image can be tailored
\end{document}
```

[image]

While one could redefine `\includegraphics`, I would strongly recommend against it.  If adding the text were too onerous for each image, one could define a `\myincludegraphics` to do this, without tampering with the original.